# Is it a good idea to use disable or conditional disable diagrams in LabVIEW to organize and help document code?

Tags: labview

I'm a fan of this right now, being a moderate LabVIEW programmer (several years experience off and on), but I wonder what other LabVIEW programmers think.

I like to use conditional-disable-diagrams as a way to organize and document my code.  I organize sections of the code into a conditional disable diagram with only one page (enabled), then use a comment at the top to describe what's going on.

The nice thing is that you can arrange things in the diagram the way you want them and tell LabVIEW to never auto-arrange it.  LabVIEW will then treat the entire block as a single unit when auto-arranging.  If you do this a lot, you can always use the global auto-arrange feature to nicely layout your code.

Also, this makes LabVIEW code very easy to read and follow.

Is this a good idea?  Do other LabVIEW programmers do it?  If it's a bad idea, what's the downside?

Comment: This question asks for opinion on code quality. Stack Overflow standards for "reasonable subjectivity" should apply to answers. If you haven't read that community standard, it is here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 1):

So I don't see any reason this is inherently bad and I have cases where I do similar things. I would just consider a couple of things though:

1. I would use a flat sequence structure frame, this has the same effect and it is easier to read since you know no other case is being used. The I use the subdiagram labels for documentation.
2. I would however consider whether you should be using more subVIs. Having distinct groups of code with a single purpose calls out for forming into a subVI which makes the top level code easier to read. That fact that you want to treat this differently from the other code i.e avoid clean up also suggests at least some of these should be subVIs. The final nail in the coffin is if you ever copy them anywhere else they should 100% be subVIs (might be even if not)

Answer (score -1):

Using the diagram disable structure for code documentation is not a good idea for several reasons.

1. Although you know that it is a sub-diagram with only one frame this can't be seen by any other programmer at a glance, they need to find that out be browsing, making the code less readable. Using a flat sequence structure (as suggested by [jamesmc86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3895506/jamesmc86) is than the better option, although I would also not propose that).
2. The enable/disable diagram severs a purpose, mainly debugging and testing. If a programmer happens on such a structure he expects a part of the program that is still undergoing test, an alternative implementation of an algorithm that is not quite working yet or some other test. Or upon noticing that there is no disable case, assumes it was a test case that not was removed and thinks it is sloppy programming.
3. If documentation becomes so comprehensive (more than one or two phrases where a label will do) that structures are needed, than sub-VIs should be made where the proper structure for documentation is implemented.
4. Don't use programming structures for layout effects. Using programming structures increases the overhead of the actual program and increases changes of bugs. If really necessary use labels and/or decorations. I know they are not interactive with code and as such can be annoying but if code is programmed in a nice and structured manner it should not be a problem.

Overall I would say that if the diagram disable/enable structure is used for code documentation you are not using enough sub-VIs.

Comment: Point #3 and #4 are reasonable points. But I'm down voting for points #1 and #2.  The author says he has the enabled frame visible. So it doesn't matter if there are additional frames. Your point #1 is irrelevant. Your point #2 is false. DDS and CDS are frequently in shipping code... leaving the debug and trace points in is fine and makes building release easier. Not having additional frames just means it is a code region that is sometimes useful to turn off while working. I don't see anything sloppy about it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation although I am not totally in agreement with you. For point #1 although the enabled frame is visible I would still be curious to what code is in the other part and in my opinion it adds clutter. For #2, I am not saying that shipping code with DDS and/or CDS is bad practice, but exactly that people would expect it for debugging and tracing while here it is not used in that way but purely for layout purposes. It is that use case that I find not so clean.

Comment: @djklomp I can see your argument.